# how to decode a qrcode using zxing through webcam

Tags: java, qr-code

i have a code to decode a qrcode that take a image file and decode it. am using zxing library. but how can i make this capture qrcode from webcam and decode it. what are the changes i need to do?? can any one plz explain this step by step.

here is the code:

```
public class QrCodeDecoder
{
    public String decode(File imageFile)
    {
         BufferedImage image;
         try
         {
             image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
         } 
         catch (IOException e1)
         {
         return "io outch";
         }

         // creating luminance source
         LuminanceSource lumSource = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
         BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(lumSource));

         // barcode decoding
         QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();
         Result result = null;
         try {
             result = reader.decode(bitmap);
         } 
         catch (ReaderException e)
         {
         return "reader error";
         }

         return result.getText();

         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty far away from a solution, I don't think anyone can explain it "step by step".  You will first need to find a library that is capable of grabbing an image from a webcam.  You might start with [this library](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture), though I'm sure there are others.

Once you can capture an image, start to figure out if it is in a format that the above code expects.  If you are lucky, it will be, if not you will have to convert between the two formats.